# Can't increase / decrease data property value in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I am new in Vue.js and facing a simple problem in Vue reactivity. I am trying to increase or decrease a value in a data property and also update another dependent value in real-time. Here is my code demonstration:

https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-http-srkz0?file=/src/App.vue

```html
<div v-for="(product,index) in products" :key="index" style="padding-top:10px">
   <button @click="decrement(product.quantity)">-</button> 
   {{product.quantity}}
   <button @click="increment(product.quantity)">+</button>
   {{product.title}} 
   costs ${{calculateSubtotal(product.price,product.quantity)}}
</div>
```

```js
data(){
  return{
    products:[
      {
       title:'ball',
       quantity: 2,
       price: 25
      },
      {
       title:'bat',
       quantity: 1,
       price: 79
      },
    ]
  }
},
methods:{
  increment(n){
    return n+=1;
  },
  decrement(n){
    return n-=1;
  },
  calculateSubtotal(price,quantity){
    return price*quantity
  }
}
```

Expected Output:
The buttons should work to increase or decrease the value and calculate the costs in real-time. Can anybody help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the whole `product` to the methods:

```html
<button @click="decrement(product)">-</button> 
{{product.quantity}}
<button @click="increment(product)">+</button>
{product.title}}
```

And modify them like this:

```js
increment(p){
   p.quantity += 1;
},
decrement(p){
   p.quantity -= 1;
},
```

Otherwise, the method is only receiving a copy of the value and modifying that instead of the object property.

You could do it without any methods like this:

```html
<button @click="product.quantity--">-</button> 
{{product.quantity}}
<button @click="product.quantity++">+</button>
{{product.title}}
```

Comment: It works @Dan. Thank you! Can you please answer me another question that, how can a remove an item from the list. here is the way I am thinking the stuff https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-http-srkz0?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: You're welcome.  The easiest way to remove would be like this:  `<button @click="products.splice(index, 1)">Remove</button>`.  Or you could pass the index to a `remove(index)` method and call this:  `this.products.splice(index, 1)`

Comment: Works! But how can I use Vue.delete here @Dan?

Comment: `<button @click="$delete(products, index)">Remove</button>`. Or you could pass the index to a `remove(index)` method and call this: `this.$delete(this.products, index)`